# How to recognize repeated hidden words in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I’m trying to code something that would do the following. Suppose that you were given a string neighneigh. You are told that the root word is neigh. Now you need to find how many horses are there. In this case there is one. If it was neignheigh, it would be 2 horses since before the first horse could finish neighing, another horse interrupted it.

Tried using lists, but in hindsight using dictionary and keeping track of the position of where the beginning of the sound (neigh) would be better. This seems to work for things like neighneigh (1 horse), neigh (1 horse), nneigheigh (2 horses), nnneigheigheigh (3 horses). I know it's not good code, but I'm just a novice. Any comments or if you have a better version please feel free to share, comment, etc.

```py
s = 'neighneigh'
fw=['n','e','i','g','h']
sound=[]
word=[]
index_word=[]
total = 0
break_flag=0
animal_found=0
animal_index=[]
k=0
j=0
horse=0


def check_prev_horse(animal_index,j):
    print("check_prev_horse")
    prev_horse=1
    print(animal_index,j)

    print("animal_index",len(animal_index))
    if (len(animal_index)==1):
        prev_horse==1
        return(prev_horse==1)
    else:
        for a in range(len(animal_index)):
            print(a+4,j)
            if j<= (a+4):
                return(prev_horse==1)
            else:
                return(prev_horse==0)



for i in range(len(s)):
        sound.append(s[i])
print (sound)

while j<len(sound):
    target=fw[k]
    list_letter=sound[j]
    if list_letter==target:
        print('Letter found!! list_letter: ' + list_letter + ' = target: ' + target) 
        word.append(list_letter)
        index_word.append(j)
        k=k+1
        if list_letter=='n':
            animal_index.append(j)
            horse=check_prev_horse(animal_index,j)
        if str(word)==str(fw):
            if (horse==1):
                animal_found=animal_found+1
            #if (len(sound))<(len(fw)):
            #    break_flag=1
            word=[]
            k=0
        sound[j]='x'
        j=0
    else:
        j=j+1        
print ("Total animal found: " + str(animal_found))
```

Comment: Why are there not two horses in `neighneigh`, one horse neighed and finished, then other horse neighed and finished right!

Comment: That’s possible, but we’re trying to find minimum number of horses. In the case of neighneigh, it could be 1 or 2, so we assume 1 because, and I guess I should have mentioned it, we’re trying to find the minimum number.

Comment: Okay so we can assume to only count one neigh, if they occur back to back like neighneigh or neighneighneigh, also how do you define minimum number of horses? Why is nneeiigghh the count will be 2 and not 0 or 1?